# Calling a controller method via javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET application where I am invoking a controller methode from JavaScript. My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
function OnNodeClick(s, e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("DeviceManifests", "Home")',
        data: { selectedRepo: e.node.name },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $('#GridView').html(data);
            }
        },                   
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

This calls the `Home` controller's `DeviceManifests()` method.
This is what the method looks like:

```
 public ActionResult DeviceManifests(Guid selectedRepo)
 {
    var repoItem = mock.GetRepoItem(selectedRepo);

    return View("Delete", repoItem.childs);
 }
```

The method gets invoked but the problem is the `Delete-View` doesn't get rendered. There's no error, just nothing happens.

How can I update my code to get my desired behaviour?

Comment: `return View("Delete", repoItem.childs);` will return `html`,so you have to give `dataType:'html'` in ajax call and attach success callback in ajax call to display returned html in your page.

Comment: add `success: function(data) { $('#someElement').html(data); }` to add the returned html to the DOM

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. Unfortunatly there's still nothing happening in my UI. Maybe there's a better way to change a view from within JavaScript than sending an AJAX request?

Comment: Edit your question with the updated code you have tried.

Comment: Looks OK (although should be `return PartialVew(..);` and you should add `dataType: 'html',` to the ajax options). Add `console.log(data);` to be sure you are actually returning the data.

Comment: It's working! Returning a PartialView did the job. Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like below code so if you have error you will have it in alert box or success result will rendered in DOM

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '@Url.Action("DeviceManifests", "Home")',
            data: { selectedRepo: e.node.name },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                      $('#someElement').html(data);
                    }

                }                  
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(e.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the redirect in the javascript side.

```
function OnNodeClick(s, e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET  ",
        url: '@Url.Action("DeviceManifests", "Home")',
        data: { selectedRepo: e.node.name },
        success: function (msg)
        {
            window.location = msg.newLoc;
        }
    });
}
```

Make sure you include the redirect url in action and return JsonResult and not ActionResult.  I'd also include pass the guid so that the destination Action and let it look up the data.

Comment: All this is doing is making an ajax call and immediately redirecting - what would be the point?

Comment: That's where it's not clear what is trying to be achieved.  Why can't the ajax call not be the Delete action passing the guid?  I can't see the point of having the intermediate call that just redirects to another view